# CryptSignHash Error 2148073494 "Keyset does not exist"?

Tags: c#, hash, rsa, cryptoapi

I'm using a strange language called CA-Visual Objects. I am trying to verify a hash signature I have created in C#. But on calling the CryptSignHash function I get the error code 2148073494 which I believe maps to "Keyset does not exist".

```
CryptAcquireContext( @hCryptProvider, NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0) //returns true
CryptCreateHash(hCryptProvider, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, @hHash) //returns true
CryptHashData(hHash, pData, dwDataLen, 0) //returns true
CryptImportKey(hCryptProvider, pKeyBlob, cbKeyBlob, 0, 0, @hKey) //returns true
CryptSignHashA(hHash, AT_SIGNATURE, null, 0, NULL, @dwSignLen) //returns false with error code 2148073494
```

I am not very familiar with this API, can someone tell me what "Keyset" doesn't exist exactly? Is it the AT_SIGNATURE? or something else?

This is the C# code to sign the data:

```
 private static void CreateSigningKey()
    {
        CspParameters p = new CspParameters();
        p.KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature;

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCreateSigningKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, p))
        {
            rsaCreateSigningKey.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            var parameters = rsaCreateSigningKey.ExportParameters(false);
            byte[] ex = parameters.Exponent;
            byte[] mod = parameters.Modulus;
            File.WriteAllBytes(publicSigningKeyPathMod, mod);
            File.WriteAllBytes(publicSigningKeyPathExp, ex);
            File.WriteAllText(privateSigningKeyPath, rsaCreateSigningKey.ToXmlString(true));
        }
    }


private static string Sign(byte[] plainBytes)
    {
        string signatureText;

        CspParameters parameters = new CspParameters();
        parameters.KeyNumber = (int) KeyNumber.Signature;

        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaSign = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) //signing with private sign key
        {
            rsaSign.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            rsaSign.FromXmlString(File.ReadAllText(privateSigningKeyPath)); //private sign key is held here at BP

            SHA1Managed hash = new SHA1Managed();
            byte[] hashByte = hash.ComputeHash(plainBytes);

            RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter signFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsaSign);
            signFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            byte[] signature = signFormatter.CreateSignature(hashByte);

            signatureText = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
        }
        return signatureText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed `AT_SIGNATURE` parameter as you suspected: `CryptImportKey` will create a key with a keySpec that depends on the input key blob parameter and in your case the key blob is associated with an `AT_KEYEXCHANGE`. So, the fix of your issue is to specify `AT_KEYEXCHANGE` in `CryptSignHash` call.